# php usort deep-nested subarray optimization

Tags: php

Ok Gurus,
In searching the web I have seen `usort` doing similar to my issue but nothing I found really answered this question so I am posting for advice.
I have the following array:

```
$details = array( 
[1]=>array ( 
["2022-02-12"]=>array( 
[0]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644927415), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> bool(false), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "CI" ),
[1]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644927450), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> int(1644927471), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=>  "SJ_EJ" ),
[2]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644927946), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> int(1644939760), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "SB_EB" ),
[3]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644939774), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> int(1644942307), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "SJ_EJ" ),
[4]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644942317), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> bool(false), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "SB" )), 
["2022-02-13"]=>array( ),
 ["2022-02-14"]=>array ( 
[0]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644947652), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> bool(false), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "CI" ),
[1]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644957123), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> bool(false), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "SJ" )
 ), 
["2022-02-15"]=>array( ), 
["2022-02-16"]=>array( ),
 ), 
[2]=>array( 
["2022-02-14"]=>array(
[0]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644947652), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> bool(false), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "CI" ),
[1]=>array( ["IN_PUNCH"]=> int(1644957123), ["OUT_PUNCH"]=> bool(false), ["PUNCH_TYP"]=> "SJ" ) 
) ,
["2022-02-15"]=>array( ),
["2022-02-16"]=>array( ),
["2022-02-17"]=>array( )
 )
 )
```

And I have a need to sort each date sub-array by the "IN_PUNCH" field. To do so I have this:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    if ($a['IN_PUNCH'] < $b['IN_PUNCH']) return -1;    // return -1 if $a is earlier
    return  $a['IN_PUNCH'] > $b['IN_PUNCH'];    // return 1 if $a is later, or 0 if equal
}

foreach($details as $a=> $b){
        
        foreach($b as $c => $d){
              usort($d, 'sortByOrder');
              $details[$a][$c] = $d;
                
    }
}
```

Which is doing the job, but is there a more optimized way to do this without the nested loops?

Comment: Can you add the actual array instead of this?

Answer (score 1):

Though there is nothing wrong with your approach. But you can also use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to achieve the same thing. Try this

```
$details = array_map(function($array){ // ~ outer foreach
    return array_map(function($arr){ // ~ inner foreach
        usort($arr, function($a, $b){ // ~ sortByOrder function
            $a = $a['IN_PUNCH'];
            $b = $b['IN_PUNCH'];
            return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? -1 : 1);
        });

        return $arr;
    }, $array);
}, $details);
```

Comment: I will try this and compare the performance. I also edited the original post array. Sorry about that!

Comment: so the results are in, and it appears the nested-loops are just a bit quicker than `array_map`:
Using the above (albeit small) array to sort:
Nested Loops: .0503 ms
nested array_map: .0512 ms
Hardly a difference, but a difference none the less.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't see the _"optimized"_ part. I thought you just didn't like the nested `foreach`'s. `foreach` is always faster.

Comment: sorry about that- the `foreach` does look kinda clunky but at the end of the day performance is more important than beauty :-) Gave your response an up-vote; it is helpful and I am sure someone will make use of it.